# How to bundle Typescript library With CSS Module and SCSS using rollup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, rollupjs, css-modules

Hello my project is a component library written in typescript and react that I could reuse in other projects as an npm package. I use rollup to transpile my code when I want to use css modules with sass I followed the documentation indicating in my configuration file rollup.config.js:

```
postcss({
  modules: true,
  use: ['sass'],
}),
```

Except that when I build and I use my library in another project the style is not added to the components while when I switch to css or scss without using css module I have the styles for my components when I use them in another application. Is this because CSS module renames the classes with a unique identifier creating a reference problem for the component used in another project ?

Thank you for your help.